# AMP Twitter fallback when tweet deleted

Tags: amp-html

I'm trying to add the Twitter AMP component to a page, however I'm trying to figure out how to deal with tweets that were deleted. I know it's possible to set a `<blockquote>` placeholder, but unfortunately, due to my set up, I only get the URL of the tweet, which cannot to be used to access the tweet and get the text.

I've tried using the `<blockquote>` to display an error message, which seemed to work, however when tested with a tweet that exists, the error message/placeholder is still displayed, until the component is fully loaded.

Is there a different way of displaying an error message? It seems like only Facebook has built in functionality for this. Alternatively, can anyone think of a way to hide the `<blockquote>` error message until the component is fully loaded (preferably in CSS).

[Here's the current behaviour.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQv4Q.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible as amp-twitter does not support `placeholder` elements. I've created [a feature request](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/9355) for the AMP runtime.